# Can I pass a variable from .env file into .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, yaml, environment-variables, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm quite new to CI/CD and basically I'm trying to add this job to Gitlab CI/CD that will run through the repo looking for secret leaks. It requires some API key to be passed there. I was able to directly insert this key into .gitlab-ci.yml and it worked as it was supposed to - failing the job and showing that this happened due to this key being in that file.

But I would like to have this API key to be stored in .env file that won't be pushed to a remote repo and to pull it somehow into .gitlab-ci.yml file from there.

Here's mine

```
stages:
  - scanning

gitguardian scan:
  variables:
    GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY: ${process.env.GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY}
  image: gitguardian/ggshield:latest
  stage: scanning
  script: ggshield scan ci
```

The pipeline fails with this message: `Error: Invalid API key.` so I assume that the way I'm passing it into variables is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CI variables should be available in gitlab-runner(machine or container) as environment variables, they are either predefined and populated by Gitlab like the list of predefined variables [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), or added by you in the settings of the repository or the gitlab group **Settings > CI/CD > Add Variable**.

After adding variables you can use the following syntax, you can test if the variable has the correct value by echoing it.

```
variables:
   GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY: "$GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY"
script:
   - echo "$GITGUARDIAN_API_KEY"
   - ggshield scan ci
```

Comment: I added the following to the environment setup in Gitlab however still getting the same error. Though I was wondering, there's a note in CI/CD Settings / Variables that says the following: "Environment variables are configured by your administrator to be protected by default." 

Could it be still ignoring those env variables because of this?

Comment: actually the problem was indeed that I initially made it only accessible for protected branches. After I removed that check it all worked. Thanks!

Comment: You figured it out, Hails.